# Does continuity of $f(z)$ imply that of $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, differential

I was stuck on a problem with complex-valued functions. Here is the question:

If a function $f(z)$ is continuous at a point $z=z_0$, then does this imply that the induced function $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is continuous at $z=z_0$? Much help required. Thank you so much!!

Comment: The composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking whether we could come up with a more specific $\epsilon-\delta$ type argument on this one.

Comment: Then mimic the general epsilon-delta proof that the composition of continuous functions is continuous and  specialise it for the functions $\overline{}, f$

Comment: Well, now that you know the answer, you can go ahead and try to prove it. If you get stuck, try looking at the epsilon-delta proof for the general case of the composition of two functions. You could probably adapt that.

Comment: But i was confused. In the usual statement we have like: if $f$ is continuous at $x=a$ and $g$ is continuous at $x=f(a)$ then the composite $g(f(x))$ is continuous at $a$. However in this question, we do not know whether $f(z)$ is continuous at $\overline{z_0}$.

Comment: As noted in the other comments, it does. It's perhaps a little more surprising that holomorphicity of $z \mapsto f(z)$ implies holomorphicity of $z \mapsto \overline{f(\overline{z})}$.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC The claim is false, see Udi Fogiel answer.

Comment: @FShrike The claim is false, see Udi Fogiel answer.

Comment: @jjagmath Agh, I did not see that the OP demanded this for a specific point. The claim is true if $f$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: What is the domain of the original function $f$?

Comment: @FShrike Did you read only the title? The question says "at a point $z= z_0$"

Comment: Good reading, @jjagmath. I didn't even think that they could be asking that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, in fact the induced function isn't even guaranteed to be defined at that point. For example take a look at the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-i}$. $f(z)$ is continuous at $-i$, but $\overline{f(\overline{z})}=\frac{1}{z+i}$ is not continuous at $-i$.

Comment: Continuous is usually interpreted to mean “continuous on its domain”. If you claim that $1/(z-i)$ is continuous, how can you claim that $1/(z+i)$ is not?

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe  The question, as i understood it, is about continuity at a point.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe The question clearly states "continuous at a point $z=z_0$".

Comment: Maybe add "The induced function isn't even guaranteed to be defined at that point.", to emphasize just how far from true the claim is?

Comment: So sorry. Should have read more carefully.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thank you, i've added your suggestion to my answer